# Android Studio The following classes could not be found - com.tyczj.extendedcalendarview.ExtendedCalendarView

Tags: android, view, calendar

I'm new to android development and I want to import Extended calendar view to my project. I'm using Android Studio 1.4.1. I followed all the instructions on [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zVX32JkuwMQ) video where a guy explains how to import ExtendedCalendarView library, but in the end I get this rendering problem:

```
The following classes could not be found:
- com.tyczj.extendedcalendarview.ExtendedCalendarView
```

Basically very similar problem to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658577/cannot-instantiate-extendedcalendarview-in-eclipse), but with Android Studio.

What could be a solution to this problem? Maybe I'm importing library the wrong way? If so, what would be a correct way? As I said, followed the same steps as on the video, so is the guy even showing the correct way for this? I need help to understand this.

Comment: Did you add a dependency to your build.gradle?

Comment: I should probably update this library since it is terribly out of date

Comment: Yes, I added dependancy, build.gradle looks like this

`dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile project(':extendedCalendarView')
}`

Comment: Maybe someone got a suggestion for a similar library then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you follow the Instructions at GitHub. https://github.com/tyczj/ExtendedCalendarView

For example, He states to add this to your AndroidMainifest XML file.

```
<provider
android:name="com.tyczj.extendedcalendarview.CalendarProvider"
android:authorities="com.tyczj.extendedcalendarview.calendarprovider" />
```

Comment: yes, I did all of that. Now I'm facing with a new problem, I tried adding any older library to my project, and I get this gradle error:
`Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.`

Comment: It sounds like you have syntax errors. Check for those first. Then Run Rebuild clean project. You might consider starting a new project. As I suspect you have removed items that the Project needs to run. You have to be careful using the delete key.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted as answer on behalf of the OP).*

I added `build.gradle` to the library project and the following code inside:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}


apply plugin: 'android-library'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

    }
}
```

It works fine now.